# Null error when I'm trying to addChild

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to `addChild()` one of my *rock's 1-5* plus the *widerock*.

> TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
>       atflash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
>       atsquareslide_fla::MainTimeline/loop()[squareslide_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:10]

You can see what I've written so far below.

```
import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.events.TouchEvent; 
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);

function loop(e:Event)
{
    rock1.rotation +=10;
    rock2.rotation +=10;
    rock3.rotation +=10;
    rock4.rotation +=10;
    rock5.rotation +=10; 
    widerock.rotation +=10;
    rock1.y +=10;
    rock2.y +=10;
    rock3.y +=10;
    rock4.y +=10;
    rock5.y +=10;  
    widerock.y +=10;

    if (rock1.y >= 872.9)
    {
        rock1.y = -46.75;
    } 
    if (rock2.y >= 872.9)
    {
        rock2.y = -84.75;
    }
    if (rock3.y >= 872.9)
    {
        rock3.y = -69.75;
    }
    if (rock4.y >= 872.9)
    {
        rock4.y = -230.9;
    }
    if (rock5.y >= 872.9)
    {
        rock5.y = -230.9;
    } 
    if (widerock.y >= 872.9)
    {
        widerock.y = -547.8;
    } 
}
```

Comment: check if `rock1` existing on main stage

Comment: rock1 does exist on the main stage

Comment: Can you post your `rock.as` code?  Where in your project do you declare the `rock1` variable?

Comment: `rock1` is clearly null. Where are you placing this code? On a frame? You have to be sure that your movie clip isn't only named `rock1` but ALSO has an `instance name` of `rock1`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using addChild()?

Is your moviclip at your library and did you export as a symbol?
If yes, you need to do this:

```
var myRock1 = new rock1();
addChild(myRock1);
```

Comment: When I inserted that ^^^ I said "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method rock1".What does that mean?

Comment: Do you have any movieclip on the stage or library?

Comment: I have all of the rocks in my library and on my stage

Comment: Click at one rock, open the property window and look for the field called *instance name*, fill in with *rock1*

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a new movieclip called rock1?  You need to create and define the movieclip before you can add it to the stage.  The function rock1() should contain calls to drawing it and adding event listeners.

I found this website to be a very helpful tutorial on some basics of AS3:
http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/as3/how-to-create-a-platform-game-in-as3-part-1/